# LEGO Jurassic World Dinosaur spawn Pads

Tags: lego-jurassic-world

In LEGO jurassic world, I have unlocked the Velociraptor, Diloposaurus, Pachycephalosaurus, all the babies, Triceratops, Stegosaurus, Parasauropholus, T rex, and Brachiosaurus. I have finished the first two films, Jurassic Park and JP Lost World. When I go to the dino spawner in the Gallimimus Territory, I can select all dinos but the Stegosaurus, yet I have unlocked the Stegosaurus. How do I get the Stegosaurus and Pachycep on my menu? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to be on a bigger pad for bigger dinosaurs